# getting value from other class

Tags: java

I want to get the ID number that user use to log in to only display data that is related to this user ID, if it make sense. This is my code for the index bean(index.java), just getting the ID from a simple inputText:

```
    private String id;

    public String getid() {
    return id;
}

public void setid(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

and this is the code to user it(class table)

```
public class table {
    index i = new index();
    final String pNo=i.getid();
public List<index> getMyList()
{
     List<index> list = new ArrayList<index>();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
     Connection con = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     try
     {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/try", "root", "");

        String sql = "SELECT task.tNo, clientcase.name "+
        "FROM clientcase join task on clientcase.cNo = task.cNo "+
        "Where task.responsiblePNo = ? AND (task.statue='opened'Or task.statue= 'pending')";
        pstmt= con.prepareStatement(sql); 
        pstmt.setString(1, pNo);
        rs= pstmt.executeQuery(); 
        while (rs.next())
        {

            i.settNo(rs.getString("task.tNo"));
            i.setCompanyName(rs.getString("clientcase.name"));

            list.add(i);
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
```

I also have a jsf page haveing this code to get id, if this make any sense:

```
     <h:inputText id="personnelID" value ="#{index.id}"/>
```

My problem is I can get the ID number. If I replace the get method in table class to a real number, everything works fine. But now it just returns null. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable.

Comment: It doesn't look like id is being initialized to anything and it's not being set by your table class with i.setId(_).  Hence, when you do i.getId() it will return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
index i = new index();
final String pNo=i.getid();
```

is being run when the `table` is first created, and presumably this sets `pNo` to null.  But after that, you can't change it in any way.  You probably want a constructor for `table` that allows you to set `pNo`, so that you can pass in the value from the field.

Comment: I thought i set the ID in the jsf page, where "value ="#{index.id}""

Comment: That's not going to change the value of `pNo`.

Comment: but then how can I actually use the value i got there then??? I can scratch the whole code, just really want to pass that value to different bean class.

Comment: Use `i.getId()` when you need it, after `i` has been set.  Right now, you're calling `i.getId()` right at the beginning, before `i` has even been set, and storing the result for future use.  Get rid of `pNo` altogether.

Comment: that's totally fine with me, but how do i get the value of the id where user insert into jsf page to my "table" class?

Comment: Call `i.getId()` when you need the `id`.

Comment: so now i got rid of pNo, and changed it to this code
      index i = new index();
      pstmt.setString(1, i.getId());
and it still get null value...

Comment: So can you use your debugger to check that `i` has actually been set to the value on your JSF form?  If not, then the issue is with your JSF, not your database code.  If `i` has actually been set, then try checking whether the data you're expecting is actually present in the database, with the right value for `responsiblePNo`.

Comment: i dont understand... isn't i just representing calling method from index class? and I think the database part is fine, when i change the i.getId() to an actual number everything runs smooth like a baby butt.

Comment: `i` isn't a method; it's the object that you're trying to populate from your JSF form.  Do you know how to use your debugger to check what it's been set to?

Comment: Ok. then i think the i in i.getId() is definitely wrong. and no i never used debugger, i am very new with programming... What kind of code would u use to get the value from a jsf form to 2 different classes?

Comment: You probably want to look for a good JSF tutorial online if this is the part you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a constructor in your index class and set the Id there like

```
public class index
{
    private String id;

    public String getid() {
    return id;
}

public void setid(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public index(string Id)
{
  this.setid(Id);
}
}
```

Then in your table class you can instantiate index like below; in that way it will make sure that ID value is set and you don't get `NULL` if first time you are creating a object of `index` and trying to get ID value

```
public class table {
index i = new index("1234");
final String pNo=i.getid();
```

Comment: But i want to get the id from the jsf page... if i do so wouldn't I have to insert the ID myself?

Comment: @user3677469, OK get the Id from wherever and then while instantiating index, pass the same ID to the constructor. make sense?

Comment: hmmmmmm... I think i need a bit in code :) u can see i suck at this

Comment: @user3677469, that's alright while you are learning. don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use

```
setid(String)
```

anywhere? 
Otherwise  `id`   has its default value, which is `null`.

Comment: well, im hoping i can get it from a jsf input.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `index` instance

```
index i = new index();
```

It's created with no value in `id` member. You should initialize the object properly or get supplied with an initialized one prior this line:

```
final String pNo=i.getid();
```